How to create an Android SecretKey that is invalidated when a new finger print is enrolled
I've been strugling to achieve the following scenario:
I want to authenticate my user via biometrics, and when the user enroll a new biometry I want to invalidate the key or get an exception.
I've got something by the following code:
private fun createKey(): SecretKey {
        return try {
            val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                keyGenerator.init(
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        SyncStateContract.Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                    )
                        .setUserAuthenticationParameters(
                            AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS,
                            KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                        )
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .build()
                )
            } else {
                keyGenerator.init(
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        SyncStateContract.Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                    )
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS)
                        .build()
                )
            }

            keyGenerator.generateKey()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to generate the key.", e)
        }
    }

fun createAndEncrypt(pin: String, context: Context?) {
//         encrypt the password
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        val secretKey = createKey()
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        val encryptionIv = cipher.iv
        val passwordBytes = pin.toByteArray(charset(CHARSET_NAME))
        val encryptedPasswordBytes = cipher.doFinal(passwordBytes)
        val encryptedPassword = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedPasswordBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)

        // store the login data in the shared preferences
        // only the password is encrypted, IV used for the encryption is stored
        val editor = UserPreferences.getUserPreferences(context!!).edit()
        editor.putString(UserPreferences.PREF_USUER_PASS, encryptedPassword)
        editor.putString(UserPreferences.PREF_USUER_PASS_IV, Base64.encodeToString(encryptionIv, Base64.DEFAULT))
        editor.apply()
    }

companion object {
        private const val CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8"
        private const val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
        const val TRANSFORMATION = (KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
        private const val AUTHENTICATION_DURATION_SECONDS = 30
    }

After this, when the user has his biometry successfully  read I retrieve the key to use for my decryption.
The problem is that in some cases it works fine, but in some devices like a Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 in the moment of creating the key, more specific in the method createKey() in the point 'keyGenerator.generateKey()', I keep getting the following error: java.security.ProviderException: Keystore key generation failed.
(And other problem is that, looks like I can't know if the user enrolled another biometry, under API 30.
Does anyone know how to deal with it, please?!
